# How to escape a # within a SQL CONCAT for anchor in URL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm setting up a database query to access and link to comments, but I am having trouble escaping the # symbol within the CONCAT. Here is my current query:

```
SELECT c.subject, CONCAT('node/', c.nid, '/comment-', c.cid) FROM {comments} c WHERE c.subject LIKE LOWER(:like_word)
```

Which creates urls like this: node/1234/comment-1234

I need to include the # to create a url like so: node/1234/#comment-1234 but that doesn't work due to the # sign.

```
SELECT c.subject, CONCAT('node/', c.nid, '/#comment-', c.cid) FROM {comments} c WHERE c.subject LIKE LOWER(:like_word)
```

Comment: Seems to be working fine on [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/21227)

Comment: Drupal's comment table is named `comment`, not `comments`...

Comment: Indeed, the query's fine. `db_query("SELECT c.subject, CONCAT('node/', c.nid, '/#comment-', c.cid) FROM comment c")->fetchAll();` produces no errors in a standard D7 installation

Comment: I'm looking into this further, but just as a note this is in Drupal 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you provide some more details? You say it "doesn't work due to the # sign". How does it not work? Do you get an error? Is the resulting string not what you expected?

I tried a test here on MySQL 5.5 and got what seems like a normal response:

```
mysql> select concat('foo/', 'bar', '/#comment');
+------------------------------------+
| concat('foo/', 'bar', '/#comment') |
+------------------------------------+
| foo/bar/#comment                   |
+------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```